# Passing Accessibility props to a nested button in Material-ui-pickers Calendar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

I'm using a material-ui-pickers calendar in my app and the left and right icon arrow buttons for navigating between months are lacking aria-labels, which is a critical accessibility failure: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.5/button-name?application=axeAPI

Does anyone have suggestions about how I might pass down an aria-label into this component, or attach an aria-labelledby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vanilla JS solution would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton")[0].setAttribute("aria-label", "go to the previous month");
document.querySelectorAll(".MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton")[1].setAttribute("aria-label", "go to the next month");
```

Comment: thanks! this worked for me, just had to make it a wildcard class selector and wrap it all in a useEffect hook. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `KeyboardButtonProps` given by `KeyboardDatePicker`:

Example:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
    label={'DateText'}
    KeyboardButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'target date',
    }}
    leftArrowButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'Go to the previous month',
    }}
    rightArrowButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'Go to the next month',
    }}
/>
```

For more information, see https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker